# Is z-transforming continuous variables always necessary?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, linear, continuous-data

I fitted a LMM with two continuous variables (actually they are more like discrete variables,varying from 0-7)and a categorical variable. The summary function showed that the two continuous variables were significantly interacted.
I am not sure how to tease apart this interaction. I try to compute simple slopes, i.e., the slopes of the dependent variable on the independent variable when the moderator variable is held constant at different combinations of values from very low to very high. Now the question is I don't know if I still need to z-transform the data, because if I did, the plot didn't look right......
[image]

Comment: You need to be much more specific in describing your model. In general, if you are working with the interaction of two continuous variables, it is a very good idea to transform them into z-scores. Otherwise, the results tend to be hard to interpret. But again, it depends on the specific situation - sometimes it may be easier to interpret the coefficients obtained from the original untransformed values.

Comment: I find z-scores too hard to interpret and they depend heavily on the covariates having a symmetric distribution; otherwise the SD used in the z-score is not a good scaling quantity.  I'd rather fit on the raw data scale and to form any contrast of interest post-fit.  Such contrasts can include double differences (interaction effects).

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for replying! Could you please be more specific about forming contrasts of interest post-fit? How do you do this in R?

Comment: @DanielDostal The final model I used (without z-transforming) is like this : Y~AB+BC+(1|subj)+(1|item). A and B are continuous variables and C is a categorical variable. I computed slopes for A at different levels of B (e.g., B=1,2,3...7) using the formula : beta A + beta AB * B. Then I used the deltamethod function in R to compute standard erros and computed 95% CI. I did all this to generate a plot to show how slopes of A changes with the level of B. So in this situation (I didn't interpret the summary output directly ), do I need to z-transform the variables?

Comment: For ordinary linear models, some time-to-event models, ordinal outcome models, quantile regression, Cox models and binary logistic regression the R `rms` package `contrast` function (full name `contrast.rms`) makes this easy.  You state the predictor combinations for which you want predictions - either 1, 2, or 4 such combinations.   For 4 combinations you get double differences, conifidence limits, and p-values.  See the many examples in the [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rms/versions/6.2-0/topics/contrast.rms).

Comment: It seems to me that a lot of scaling in regression models comes from neural networks having convergence issues when you don't do that. For a linear model that you want to interpret, instead of a black-box neural network, that seems less important.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to Z-transform a continuous predictor for standard types of regression models.* Some prefer to center such predictors about their mean values when there are interactions, as it puts the "main effect" coefficients into a range that is appropriate to the data. Otherwise, for example, a "main effect" coefficient for a predictor that interacts with `age` in a model of adult cancer outcomes would be the value that holds for newborns at `age = 0`.

But you can't really interpret a "main effect" coefficient reliably without taking associated interactions into account, and the additional scaling by the standard deviation for a Z-score doesn't add anything useful. Centering and scaling don't fundamentally change the model, just the interpretation of particular coefficients.

As Frank Harrell noted in comments, the best way to tease apart interactions is to show model predictions for particular combinations of predictor values. His [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) makes this straightforward after you take the time to learn the syntax.

---

*Some software might do things like that internally to avoid convergence issues, for example when there are exponentiations involved, but then return coefficients in the original scales.